# C++ If-Else Statement Printing Multiple Statements

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am making a simple if-else statement in C++, but the code is printing out multiple statements. If I type "1", the terminal will print out "Number 1A different number". Does anyone know why multiple statements are printing?

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main() {

    cout << "Please enter a number";

    int number;

    cin >> number;

    if(number==1) {
        cout <<"Number 1";
    }

    if (number==2) {
        cout <<"Number 2";
    }
    else {
        cout <<"A different number";
    }
}
```

**Terminal**

```
Please enter a number1

Number 1A different number
```

Comment: Note that your statement is `if ... if ... else` not `if ... else if ... else`. The `else` will execute any time `number==2` is `false`, _not_ any time both `number==1` and `number==2` are false.

Comment: Tip: Learn about `switch` and other tools C++ offers.

Comment: C++ can be a little confusing, but if you step through this in a debugger it might become a lot more clear.

Comment: The programmer's secret weapon is the debugger. With a debugger you can execute the program at your speed and view the results (flow of the program and changes to variables in play) as they happen. Stepping through a problematic bit of code will almost instantly reveal most errors. Usually the hard part is finding the right bit of code to step through.

Answer (score 1):

Add `else` before `if (number==2)`

```
else if (number==2)
```

Answer (score 0):

for your else if statement you forgot to add an else in front of your next if statement so what happens is that the program checks if number = 1 it will type Number1

then it checks if the number equals two since it doesnt it prints the else statement

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

cout << "Please enter a number";

int number;

cin >> number;

if(number==1)
{
    cout <<"Number 1";
}

else if (number==2) // <<<<<<<<< Here

{
    cout <<"Number 2";
}

else

{
    cout <<"A different number";
}

}
```